# Spring - Set property value using annotations without using properties file

Tags: java, spring, spring-annotations

I have a bean class like, for example

```
class Sample {
    private String message;
    public void setMessage(String message) {
        this.message = message;
    }
    public String getMessage() {
        return message;
    }
}
```

and I want to set this property's value.

In Xml Configuration, I could do

```
<bean id = "sample" class = "Sample"
    <property name = "message" value = "Hello there!"/>
</bean>
```

How do I achieve the same thing i.e. set property's value using Java Annotation? Now I have read that we can use @Value annotation using some properties file but cannot it be done without using properties file, doing the way I did it through xml file? Or using properties file is **necessary**?

I was able to do it by including `@Value("Hello there!")` above the setter method. But I could feel that is not a good idea. How to set the property values for different instances using Java Annotations?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The value inserted into the `@Value` can come from places other than a properties file, for example it can also use system properties.

Using the guide [here](http://www.baeldung.com/spring-value-annotation) as a starting point should help you understand a little better.

> As a basic and mostly useless usage example we can only inject “string
>   value” from the annotation to the field:
>
> ```
> @Value("string value")
> private String stringValue;
> ```
>
> Using the @PropertySource annotation allows us to work with values
>   from properties files with the @Value annotation. In the following
>   example we get “Value got from the file” assigned to the field:
>
> ```
> @Value("${value.from.file}")
> private String valueFromFile;
> ```
>
> We can also set the value from system properties with the same syntax.
>   Let’s assume that we have defined a system property named systemValue
>   and look at the following sample:
>
> ```
> @Value("${systemValue}")
> private String systemValue;
> ```
>
> Default values can be provided for properties that might not be
>   defined. In this example the value “some default” will be injected:
>
> ```
> @Value("${unknown.param:some default}")
> private String someDefault;
> ```

Answer (score 0):

You have a few options, depending on your requirements. In both of these examples you can set the annotation on a setter instead of the field.

### Custom PropertySource

This lets you continue using `@Value` with greater control for how the properties are supplied. There are a large number of `PropertySource` implementations, but you can always create your own.

References:

- [How to add custom property source to Spring's Environment](https://coderwall.com/p/mm5ihw/how-to-add-custom-property-source-to-spring-s-environment)
- [PropertySource JavaDoc](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/core/env/PropertySource.html)

Example:

```
@Configuration
class MyConfiguration {
  @Bean
  PropertySource myPropertySource(ConfigurableEnvironment env) {
    MapPropertySource source = new MapPropertySource("myPropertySource", singletonMap("myPropertyValue", "example"));
    env.getPropertySources().addFirst(source);
    return source;
  }
}

class Sample {
  @Value("${myPropertyValue}")
  private String message;

  public String getMessage() {
    return message;
  }
}
```

### String Bean

Define a bean as a String and auto-wire it using its qualifier.

Example:

```
@Configuration
class MyConfiguration {
  @Bean
  String myPropertyValue() {
    String value;
    // do something to get the value
    return value;
  }
}

class Sample {
  @Autowired
  @Qualifier("myPropertyValue")
  private String message;

  public String getMessage() {
    return message;
  }
}
```

Comment: Hi, actually I wanted to set it using Annotation based configuration. Configuration and Bean annotations come under Java Based configuration, I assume?